# My headphones have 4 wires instead of just 3

Tags: repair, headphones

I cut into my headphone cable to repair the headphone plug and instead of the standard "3 wires" I read about all the time mine has four:

- 1 red (I assume right)
- 1 blue (I assume left)
- 1 white (???)
- 1 black (???)

These headphones don't have a microphone, so it's not for audio in.

UPDATE: I looked at some other documentation about this brand's design, turns out it's "left earth" and "right earth".

Comment: My guess would be separate ground wires for each side.

Comment: Have you looked at the driver side yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plug only has three and there are four wires (and its a nicer pair of headphones) it is probable that the current return is not shared in the cable.

Get a multi meter an ohm out the pairs (set it on ohm mode), if the headphones are (say) 8Ω then if you put the positive on the blue and the negative on the white, then it should say 8Ω if those are a pair, if not then try the black. Then try the same thing with the red until you have them sorted out.

You might be able to ohm out the cut cable on the 3.5mm end, if you still have it. Put one of the meter cables on one of the 3.5mm jack and then test all the pairs until you have continuity, then you can match them to the new jack.

Don't ask me what ohming does, you'll need to research that yourself, its an EE forum after all

Comment: Note that only knowing which wires pair together isn't enough; if one of the drivers is reversed then the audio from the headphones will sound... "off".

Comment: Its a speaker, polarity doesn't matter. And if you match up the pairs to the 3.5mm jack you'll be fine

Comment: @laptop2d it does if you get the two speakers out of phase with each other.  The human brain is sensitive to phase differences between the two ears - that's how you tell which direction a sound is from.  If they are 180 degrees out of phase, the result just makes no sense, and it sounds wrong.

Comment: I looked at some other documentation about this brand's design, turns out it's "left earth" and "right earth".